# Add the value of the last row to to this row

Tags: python, pandas, transformation, data-wrangling

I want to get the value of the last row when grouping by Name. For instance, the last iteration of the name Walter in row 2, I want to get Dog + ", " + Cat for Col1 and Beer + ", " + Wine in Col3. There are a lot of columns, so I would like to make it based on indexing/column position instead of column names.

```
+------+---------+-------+
| Col1 |  Name   | Col3  |
+------+---------+-------+
| Dog  | Walter  | Beer  |
| Cat  | Walter  | Wine  |
| Dog  | Alfonso | Cider |
| Dog  | Alfonso | Cider |
| Dog  | Alfonso | Vodka |
+------+---------+-------+
```

This is the output I want:

```
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
|     Col1      |           Name            |        Col3         |
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| Dog           | Walter                    | Beer                |
| Dog, Cat      | Walter, Walter            | Beer, Wine          |
| Dog           | Alfonso                   | Cider               |
| Dog, Dog      | Alfonso, Alfonso          | Cider, Cider        |
| Dog, Dog, Dog | Alfonso, Alfonso, Alfosno | Cider, Cider, Vodka |
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

This is what I have tried (but does not work):

```
for i in df:
    if df.loc[i,1] == df.loc[i+1,1]:
        df.loc[i,0] + ", " + df.loc[i+1,0]
    else:
        df.loc[i+1,0]
```

I read that iterating over rows in pandas with a for-loop is frowned upon, so I would like to get the output by using vectorization or apply (or some other efficient way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here  is another way using `accumulate` on the index and using `df.agg` method:

```
from itertools import accumulate
import numpy as np

def fun(a):
    l = [[i] for i in a.index]
    acc = list(accumulate(l, lambda x, y: np.concatenate([x, y])))
    return pd.concat([a.loc[idx].agg(','.join) for idx in acc],axis=1).T
out = pd.concat([fun(v) for k,v in df.groupby('Name',sort=False)])
```

---

```
print(out)
          Col1                     Name               Col3
0          Dog                   Walter               Beer
1      Dog,Cat            Walter,Walter          Beer,Wine
0          Dog                  Alfonso              Cider
1      Dog,Dog          Alfonso,Alfonso        Cider,Cider
2  Dog,Dog,Dog  Alfonso,Alfonso,Alfonso  Cider,Cider,Vodka
```

You can add a reset index with `drop=True` in the end to reset the indexes

Answer (score 3):

What you're basically trying to do is run a commutative aggregation function on each group. Pandas have `comsum` for regular addition but doesn't support custom commutative functions. For this you may want to use some numpy functions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["D", "C", "D", "D", "D"], "Name": ["W", "W", "A", "A", "A"], 
                   "col3": ["B", "W", "C", "C", "V"] })


import numpy as np
def ser_accum(op,ser):
    u_op = np.frompyfunc(op, 2, 1) # two inputs, one output
    return u_op.accumulate(ser, dtype=np.object)

def plus(x,y):
    return x + "," + y

def accum(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = ser_accum(plus, df[col])
    return df

df.groupby("Name").apply(accum)
```

Here's the result:

```
col1    Name    col3
0   D   W   B
1   D,C W,W B,W
2   D   A   C
3   D,D A,A C,C
4   D,D,D   A,A,A   C,C,V
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `groupby` and `cumsum`. If you don't mind (depending on your use after) having an extra comma/space at the end, you can do:

```
print (df.groupby('Name')[['Col1', 'Col3']].apply(lambda x: (x + ', ').cumsum()))
              Col1                   Col3
0            Dog,                  Beer, 
1       Dog, Cat,            Beer, Wine, 
2            Dog,                 Cider, 
3       Dog, Dog,          Cider, Cider, 
4  Dog, Dog, Dog,   Cider, Cider, Vodka,
```

but if you want to remove the extra comma/space, just add str[:-2] to each column like:

```
print (df.groupby('Name')[['Col1', 'Col3']].apply(lambda x: (x + ', ').cumsum())\
         .apply(lambda x: x.str[:-2]))
            Col1                 Col3
0            Dog                 Beer
1       Dog, Cat           Beer, Wine
2            Dog                Cider
3       Dog, Dog         Cider, Cider
4  Dog, Dog, Dog  Cider, Cider, Vodka
```

Comment: The double `apply` can be costly though, depending on frame size

Answer (score 1):

If you only care for the *last row* results of `Col1` and `Col3`, try this:

```
df.groupby('Name').agg(', '.join)
```

Result:

```
                  Col1                 Col3
Name                                       
Alfonso  Dog, Dog, Dog  Cider, Cider, Vodka
Walter        Dog, Cat           Beer, Wine
```

Comment: I also agree this is not cumulative join.  But I feel like we're picking between what OP is asking and what OP is showing in output.  Maybe OP can clarify what is the actual expected result, the shown table, or just the last row as mentioned.  We might even go further and ask, what if `Walter` shows up again after `Alfonso`, is that a new grouping, or part of the previous?

Comment: This is neat. I actually have some other use case for this line of code, and it is so short and sweet. Walter will not show up again btw.